# All the Money in the Minotaur

Tags: analysis, all-the-money-in-the-world

In the Ridley Scott film **All the Money in the World**, there is a scene in which John Paul Getty III meets his grandfather. The scene revolves around a statue of a Minotaur which the billionaire claims to be worth $1.2 million and ultimately gifts to his grandson. Later on we discover the statue is actually a cheap knockoff.

It seems incongruous with J. Paul Getty's character to suppose he was unaware of the statue's true value. In other words he was lying. Why? What does the elder Getty gain by duping his offspring about the value of a statue? They already know he is rich. And they know he is cheap because he refuses to spend $10 on laundry service immediately after giving away the Minotaur. Is the lie simply meant to highlight his pettiness for the audience?

Comment: I haven't seen the movie, but found this: ["Foremost on the mind of the film’s incredible ensemble is **the idea that the worth we place on things – and people – is only as much as we’re willing to pay for them**. This is how Getty turns unauthenticated Vermeers into million-dollar works of art, and an old minotaur artifact J. Paul gives his grandson early in the film into nothing more than a mass-produced trinket."](https://consequenceofsound.net/2017/12/film-review-all-the-money-in-the-world/)